# Removing items from multiple comboboxes

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have 7 comboboxes. All these comboboxes have same source.

`With Sheets("Data_Sheet")`

`Sheets("UI_Interface").ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "Data_Sheet!E2:E" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row`

`End With`

Same code has been written for other combobxes.

Now when a value from combobx1 is selected it should not be present in other comoboxes.
When i try to do this with following code but i'm getting error with this code.

`j = ComboBox1.ListIndex`

`ComboBox2.RemoveItem (j)`

I tried some different attributes too for removing the value but all gave some exception.

What is incorrect in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RemoveItem` method works properly for me unless I use the `.ListFillRange` method to populate the combobox. If you use the `.List` method instead, it should work.  To do that, you have to convert the range to an array.

**REVISED**

Thanks to enderland for pointing out that you are working with form controls on a worksheet, not in a user form.  So the approach should be similar but you won't be able to use the `ListFillRange` method.  Not a big deal, we can easily take that range, convert it to a variant/array, and use the `List` method.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
'## Sets default list for ComboBoxes on this sheet
    SetComboBoxLists ComboBox1
    SetComboBoxLists ComboBox2

End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
'## event handler for a combobox, repeat as needed
    '## Repopulate the list, otherwise you may get
    '    an Index out of Range error or Invalid Argument error,
    '    or the RemoveItem method will remove the wrong item
    SetComboBoxList ComboBox2
    '## Now, remove the item selected in ComboBox1
    ComboBox2.RemoveItem ComboBox1.ListIndex
End Sub

Private Sub SetComboBoxLists(cBox As MSForms.ComboBox)
'## Subroutine to fill the list in each combobox as needed
Dim lstRange As Variant

    '## Populate the array variable to use for the combobox.List method:
    '    double-check that I put the parentheses in the right place!
    With Sheets("Data_Sheet")
        lstRange = .Range("E2:E" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    '## Populate the combobox with the list
    cBox.List = lstRange

End Sub
```

Note that if any of your code manipulates (e.g., resizes, removes rows, etc) the range, you'll need to re-apply the `List` method.

Comment: My guess is the comboboxes are in the sheet itself and are tied to the specific range (which is why they don't work with what the OP is asking).

Comment: ... though I am pretty sure this will still solve the question, so here's a +1 :)

Comment: @enderland good catch. I will test that out in a bit. If it doesn't work immediately it quill be a quick fix to OP's code to first convert the range to a variant and then populate the combobox with the `.list` method, which should then allow for this.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in the question. I'm actually working with ActiveX controls on a sheet. The comboboxes have a source of a range in the 2nd sheet.